# Data of the converter and time gtm c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I get a schedule in this format `Fri, 07 Apr 2017 09:03:03 GTM`. How can I convert to this format `04/07/2017 09:03:03`?

I tried to do with the date conversion method

```
DateTime.Parse(string date);
```

But that returns `07/04/2017 06:03:03`

Comment: What is "GTM" meant to be? Did you mean GMT? If so, are you sure the original string *actually* contains GMT? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime.Parse("Fri, 07 Apr 2017 09:03:03 GMT").ToUniversalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime dd = Convert.ToDateTime( DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```

You just need to specify the format of the date when converting

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime("Fri, 07 Apr 2017 09:03:03 GTM");